# Есть ли отличие использования css media запрос в файле css или html?

Tags: html, css

Есть ли разница использования медиа запросов в одном файле css или в нескольких файлах, но при подключении в html ?

например вот так в одном файле css :

```
@media all and (min-width: 901px) and (max-width: 1200px)  {
    мой код
}

@media all and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 900px)  {
   мой код
}
```

или подключая в head html файла вот так:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 1201px)" href="css/desktop.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1200px)" href="css/tablet.css"> 

<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-width: 768px)" href="css/mobile.css">
```

будет ли какая нибудь разница?

Comment: Лично мне кажется, чем меньше файлов стилей подключено, тем быстрее скорость загрузки сайта

Comment: да, я с этим согласен, вопрос скорее в том есть ли какая то разница в обработке браузером?
потому что из практики я иногда сталкиваюсь с банальными проблемами, например сегодня у меня не все стили работали просто потому что слишком сжат был css, и на некоторых компьютерах (3 из 10 где проверяли) стили не работали как надо. А как только я перекомпрессировал с меньшим сжатием все заработало =0